# MVC jquery Insert Code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with

```
Name textbox
Address textbox
Phone textbox
Insert buttion
```

and I am trying to send the data to controller on button click as single object.

Please suggest me best way and code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery btw unless you're planning on doing the submit with jQuery.

```
<form action="/controller/action">
  <input name="Name" type="text" />
  <input name="Address" type="text" />
  <input name="Phone" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit this Shizzle!" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I do that If I wish to send Json Data as a single object to controller.

Comment: There is no single answer to that.  You need to specify your framework at the very least.  Try reading the comments and answering the questions people ask.